# Permission denied for Adafruit_MotorHAT in mod_wsgi deployed Flask app

Tags: python, flask, permissions, raspberry-pi, mod-wsgi

I'm working on a simple Flask app that is served by a RaspberryPi with an Adafruit MotorHat stacked on to it, so it can drive Stepper Motors. When running the app from command line everything works fine and the Motors can be controlled via the Flask webinterface. However when trying to deploy the app via mod_wsgi I get the following apache2 errors concerning the MotorHat library:

```
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.700209 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416] mod_wsgi (pid=1583): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp  /flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.700330 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416] mod_wsgi (pid=1583): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'.
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.700405 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.700473 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.700665 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416]     from FlaskApp import app as application
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.700706 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.700895 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416]     from newsFocus import *
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.700933 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/newsFocus.py", line 14, in <module>
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.701313 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416]     from Adafruit_MotorHAT import Adafruit_MotorHAT, Adafruit_DCMotor, Adafruit_StepperMotor
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.701362 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416]   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_MotorHAT/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.701971 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416]   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_MotorHAT/Adafruit_MotorHAT.py", line 3, in <module>
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.702522 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416]   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_MotorHAT/Adafruit_PWM_Servo_Driver.py", line 11, in <module>
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.703070 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416]   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_MotorHAT/Adafruit_PWM_Servo_Driver.py", line 35, in PWM
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.703619 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416]   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_MotorHAT/Adafruit_I2C.py", line 43, in __init__
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.704127 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416]     self.bus = smbus.SMBus(busnum if busnum >= 0 else Adafruit_I2C.getPiI2CBusNumber())
[Mon Dec 11 09:30:32.704204 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1583] [client 192.168.0.10:38416] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

How can I solve this and which user is actually running the app whe deployed via mod_wsgi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user Apache runs as doesn't have permission to access whatever file you are trying to access. See:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#access-rights-of-apache-user

Although it doesn't look like it is the case here, but another common problem is where you use a relative path name rather than absolute. See:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#application-working-directory

I would suggest ensure you are using daemon mode of mod_wsgi and set the user/group for the daemon process to whatever user has access to the file or device you are trying to access. Also look at the option for setting the home directory for the process if using relative paths and can't change them. See:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html#delegation-to-daemon-process
- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html